# How to allocate memory dynamically at a given address in C?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to allocate memory dynamically at a given address in c. I am creating a 2d array in using pointer to a pointer.The code I have written is as follows :

```
int **a;
a = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*r);
for(int i = 0;i < r;i++)
{
     if(i < r - 1 && i != 1)
     {
         a[i] = (int*)realloc(a[i],sizeof(int)*c);
         a[i + 1] = &a[i][c - 1] + 1;
     }
}
```

I know the address where I want to allocate it but I cannot use malloc(), as it is allocating the memory at some other address .I tried using realloc() but it shows run time error invalid pointer. What should I use?

Comment: Why do you want a specific address? This sounds like an XY problem - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: OT: You current code is wrong because `a[i]` is uninitialized when calling `realloc`

Comment: Actually I want to allocate memory consecutively. For eg. if the element of the last column in first row has an address of 1000, then the address of element of first column in the second row, should be 1004. If I use malloc, then the address will be something else, like for eg. 2000. How can I do it. I have already assigned the address value to a[i].

Comment: ok, but that's something completely different. All you need to do is `malloc` a 2D array. You can find several examples on SO for doing that.

Comment: When you allocate a array the elements are lying behind each other that the reason you can use the index notation so what you want to achieve is the default behavior

Comment: @Darem: This would not necessary be the case for a "jagged" array create conceptuality like the OPs does ...

Comment: @alk our right, I´m sorry that I was not clear enough because I mean the standard c-array.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 library functions defined under `<stdlib.h>` makes dynamic memory allocation in C programming. They are `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `free()`.

**Example :malloc() and free()**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, *ptr, sum = 0;

    printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    ptr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(ptr == NULL)                     
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Enter elements: ");
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", ptr + i);
        sum += *(ptr + i);
    }

    printf("Sum = %d", sum);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hm, this is *not* a 2D-array, is it?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to allocate memory consecutively.

A way to do it (*without* the use of VLAs) would be like this:

```
int ** allocate_consecutively_jagged_2d_array(size_t rows, size_t columns)
{ /* The size required is: */
  size_t s = rows * sizeof (int*) /* one pointer to int per row. */
           + rows * columns * sizeof (int) /* rows * columns ints. */

  int ** p = malloc(s);
  if (NULL != p)
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
      p[i] = &((int*)(p + rows))[i * columns];
    }
  }

  return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a comment OP says:

> Actually I want to allocate memory consecutively …

So the question is not about the specific address but about getting a consecutive layout of the 2D matrix.

One way to do that is:

```
int main()
{
    int r = 2;
    int c = 4;

    // In the line below 'a' is a pointer to an array of 'c' integers
    // so allocating 'r' * sizeof(what 'a' points to)
    // will give a consecutive memory area for holding r * c integers
    int (*a)[c] = malloc(r * sizeof *a);

    // Now the memory can be accessed through 'a' as 2D array using the syntax a[i][j]

    for (int i=0; i<r; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<c; ++j)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d] is at address %p\n", i, j, (void*)&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

```
a[0][0] is at address 0xc32010
a[0][1] is at address 0xc32014
a[0][2] is at address 0xc32018
a[0][3] is at address 0xc3201c
a[1][0] is at address 0xc32020
a[1][1] is at address 0xc32024
a[1][2] is at address 0xc32028
a[1][3] is at address 0xc3202c
```

Comment: It might we worth mentioning that this `int c = 4; int (*a)[c] = ...` requires VLAs which are with C since C99 (only) and have been made optional from C11 on ...

Answer (score -1):

How to allocate memory dynamically at a given address in C?

```
There is only one possible options is realloc. But we could not able to assurance for that, Hence we cant able to make memory in contiguous like array. Kindly find the success and failure cases.
```

> Success Case
>   *) If memory is reallocated is same page(memory allocated page for mentioned pointer) , kernel will return the same address.
>
> Failure Cases 
>   *) If memory is not present in corresponding page, It will allocate the memory is different page and kernel will return new address.
>   *) If realloc gets failed, Can't able to get the original memory for that pointer.

Kindly find the basic program for this case's

```
int main()
{
        int i = 0, j = 0, array = 4, inner_array = 4;
        int **ptr = NULL;

        ptr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*array);
        if (NULL == ptr) {
                printf("Malloc failed.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //Realloc for inner array
        for (i = 0; i < array; i++) {
                //printf("Address of ptr[%d] : %p\n", i, &ptr[i]);
                ptr[i] = (int *)realloc(ptr[i], sizeof(int) *inner_array);
                for (j = 0; j < inner_array; j++) {
                        ptr[i][j] = i+j;
                }
        }

        //Print the array value & address
        for (i = 0; i < array; i++) {
                //printf("Address of ptr[%d] : %p\n", i, &ptr[i]);
                for (j = 0; j < inner_array; j++) {
                        printf("%d ", ptr[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}
```

Comment: This  `realloc(ptr[i], ...)` invokes undefined behaviour as all `ptr[i]` are used uninitialised.